# Trying to create a table and insert into the database

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlconnection

I expect the following code to check to see if a table exists on the database, and if not to create it. If "exists" == 0 it doesn't exist, if "exists" = 1, it exists. After running this code "exists" is still == 0. What am I missing?Thanks:

EDIT: As soon as I pass over "command.ExecuteNonQuery()" it throws an error.

```
var dif = new DataInterfaceFactory(DatabaseTypes.SqlServer, "DATABASE_NAME", "[SERVER_NAME]");

using (DataReader dr = dif.GetDataReader())
{
    dr.ExecuteReader("SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'");

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var exists = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TABLECOUNT"]);
        
        if (exists == 0)

        {
            var conStr = "Data Source = [SERVER_NAME]; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30; Encrypt = False; TrustServerCertificate = False; ApplicationIntent = ReadWrite; MultiSubnetFailover = False";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                try
                {                                 
                    con.Open();
                    
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE_NAME.TABLE_NAME(TABLE_NAME_UID INT,SERVER_NAME char(25),DATATABLE_NAME char(20),LAST_CHECK_DATE DATE,IS_RUNNING INT);", con))
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: could not create TABLE_NAME");
                }
            }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Why not just `CREATE TABLE CALCULATION_SCHEDULE...` instead of `CREATE WDM_SOFTWARE_INFO.TABLE CALCULATION_SCHEDULE...` ?

Comment: Im wondering since im seeing the connection to the database before conecting yourself is the query working at all? does the dr return something?

Comment: You are creating the table inside the while loop which is causing the same table to be created multiple tiles.

Comment: @Petaflop, just to make sure that it is going to be created in the right database

Comment: Instead of `ExecuteReader()` you can use `ExecuteScalar()` for the query getting the count from the catalog. And you should also include the schema in the query to the catalog. A table with the same name may exist in different schemas, which might lead to false positives with your query,

Comment: @nalnpir, yes I have checked and the "dr.ExecuteReader..." query is definitely working thanks to the dif and the DataReader

Comment: @JoeJoeJoe: The syntax is `CREATE TABLE <table name>`, where `<table name>` can optionally be qualified with the schema. Your `WDM_SOFTWARE_INFO` belongs to the table name, **not** the `TABLE` keyword.

Comment: @sticky bit, thanks I will make the adjustments, although it definitely works as I have tested "exist" against a table that exists in the database and it returns 1 as expected.

Comment: @sticky bit, whoops, my bad, that was a typo! I thought you were talking about the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem:

```
var dif = new DataInterfaceFactory(DatabaseTypes.SqlServer, "WDM_SOFTWARE_INFO", "d2sql4.d2.wdm");

            using (DataReader dr = dif.GetDataReader())
            {
                dr.ExecuteReader("SELECT COUNT(1) AS TABLECOUNT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'CALCULATION_SCHEDULE'");

                var exists = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TABLECOUNT"]);

                CommandExecutor CE = dif.GetCommandExecutor();
                try
                {
                    if (exists == 0)
                    {
                        string sql = "CREATE TABLE dbo.CALCULATION_SCHEDULE(CALCULATION_SCHEDULE_UID INT,SERVER_NAME char(25),DATATABLE_NAME char(20),LAST_CHECK_DATE DATE,IS_RUNNING INT)";
                        CE.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: could not create CALCULATION_SCHEDULE");
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ] test it, It's good way for check. Be sure of the ConnectionStrig's part

```
    var conStr = @"data source=d2sql4.d2.wdm\nkdes;initial catalog=WDM_SOFTWARE_INFO;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout = 30; Encrypt = False; TrustServerCertificate = False; ApplicationIntent = ReadWrite; MultiSubnetFailover = False";

    var existQuery = @"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'CALCULATION_SCHEDULE'";

    var createQuery = "CREATE TABLE [CALCULATION_SCHEDULE](CALCULATION_SCHEDULE_UID INT,SERVER_NAME char(25),DATATABLE_NAME char(20),LAST_CHECK_DATE DATE,IS_RUNNING INT)";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    if(con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        con.Open();
    var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(existQuery, con);

    var dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (!dr.HasRows)
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandText = createQuery;
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("your message");
```